# Laravel 5.5 bootstrap error

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, twitter-bootstrap-3, vue.js

I am getting below error.

> Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery. jQuery must be
>   included before Bootstrap's JavaScript.

app.js

```
require('./bootstrap');
window.Vue = require('vue');

import Vue from 'vue';
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';
Vue.use(VueRouter);

import VueAxios from 'vue-axios';
import axios from 'axios';
Vue.use(VueAxios, axios);



import App from './App.vue';
import Login from './components/Login.vue';
import Register from './components/Register.vue';
import Activity from './components/Activity.vue';
import SelectPersons from './components/SelectPersons.vue';

const routes = [
  {
      name: 'Login',
      path: '/',
      component: Login
  },
  {
      name: 'Register',
      path: '/register',
      component: Register
  },
  {
      name: 'Activity',
      path: '/activity',
      component: Activity
  },
  {
      name: 'SelectPersons',
      path: '/selectpersons',
      component: SelectPersons
  }
];

const router = new VueRouter({ mode: 'history', routes: routes});
new Vue(Vue.util.extend({ router }, App)).$mount('#app');
```

bootstrap.js

```
window._ = require('lodash');

/**
 * We'll load jQuery and the Bootstrap jQuery plugin which provides support
 * for JavaScript based Bootstrap features such as modals and tabs. This
 * code may be modified to fit the specific needs of your application.
 */

try {
    window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');

    require('bootstrap-sass');
} catch (e) {}

window.Vue = require('vue');

/**
 * We'll load the axios HTTP library which allows us to easily issue requests
 * to our Laravel back-end. This library automatically handles sending the
 * CSRF token as a header based on the value of the "XSRF" token cookie.
 */

window.axios = require('axios');

window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';

/**
 * Next we will register the CSRF Token as a common header with Axios so that
 * all outgoing HTTP requests automatically have it attached. This is just
 * a simple convenience so we don't have to attach every token manually.
 */

let token = document.head.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]');

if (token) {
    window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-CSRF-TOKEN'] = token.content;
} else {
    console.error('CSRF token not found: https://laravel.com/docs/csrf#csrf-x-csrf-token');
}

/**
 * Echo exposes an expressive API for subscribing to channels and listening
 * for events that are broadcast by Laravel. Echo and event broadcasting
 * allows your team to easily build robust real-time web applications.
 */

// import Echo from 'laravel-echo'

// window.Pusher = require('pusher-js');

// window.Echo = new Echo({
//     broadcaster: 'pusher',
//     key: 'your-pusher-key'
// });
```

Here is the file that loads every vue component or blade template pages.

```
<html>
  <head>
    {{Html::style('/css/bootstrap.css')}}
    {{Html::style('/css/style.css')}}
    {{Html::script('/js/bootstrap.js')}}
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app">
    </div>
    <script src="{{asset('js/app.js')}}"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I am using Laravel with vue. Can anybody help me to solve this issue?

Thanks

Comment: you should at least post your app.js / boostrap.js file

Comment: Also include layout file where you included js library’s

Comment: @FrankProvost  please check now.

Comment: @Yashvantsinh please check now.

Comment: @Hitendra Where is your `{{ HTML::script('/js/jquery.js') }}` file in your blade file?

Comment: on a first glance i can only see you are requriing vue and axios twice. Check the catch of your try catch where you require jquery. console log or debug there.

Comment: ohhhhhh you require bootstrap js in head while you require your js in footer

Comment: @Hitendra Please include jquery library on top of head file

Comment: I have jquery and jquery.min in my project at \node_modules\jquery\dist. Should i copy both files to resources\assets\js?

Comment: try import 'jquery/src/jquery' instead of this line window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your app.js contains jquery. so do as the error says and load bootstrap after jquery.

```
<html>
  <head>
    {{Html::style('/css/bootstrap.css')}}
    {{Html::style('/css/style.css')}}
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app">
    </div>
    <script src="{{asset('js/app.js')}}"></script>

    {{Html::script('/js/bootstrap.js')}}
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This resolves the jQuery error but now getting other error. "Uncaught Error: Bootstrap dropdown require Popper.js"

Comment: One more question. How did you identify that app.js contains jquery?

Comment: well you've added it in your `bootstrap.js` file. `window.$ = require('jQuery');`

Comment: Can you please tell me why i m getting other error about popper.js? I will accept your answer as it resolves the issue that i asked.

Comment: from what you've showed i can't see a popper.js library. Therfore I cannot help you - sorry. You probably need to load popper.js before loading bootstrap. Try to read through the bootstrap logo

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap required `jQuery` to run some of its features like the `dropdown`. the error says `"Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery. jQuery must be included before Bootstrap's JavaScript."`. So first, require the jquery library, then next is the `bootstrap.min.js` or `bootstrap.js`. Please feel free to comment if you have any problem with this. And one more thing, it is better to place your all `JS` files before `</body>`.

**Try this**

```
<html>
  <head>
    {{Html::style('/css/bootstrap.css')}}
    {{Html::style('/css/style.css')}}
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app">
    </div>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    {{Html::script('/js/bootstrap.js')}}
    <script src="{{asset('js/app.js')}}"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```